# NatTable Cell Painter doesn't work for column after dragging it to first position

Tags: nattable

I have a NatTable setup, but if I drag a column to first position, the painted values in the cells are gone. I see some other values there ( actually strings representing the object's values themselves)

Answer (score 0):

This is typically an issue with the registering of the IDisplayConverters to the columns. Please check that your converters are registered correctly and that the labels are registered per index. Typically you need to register a column label accumulator to the DataLayer where index == position. If you register the accumulator on top you will have issues regarding the index-position transformation.